# Java bytecode decompiler Intellij disable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bytecode, decompiler

Does anyone know how to disable Intellij's Java bytecode decompiler?
I accidentally clicked on ACCEPT and now all java files are redirected to .class instead of .java.

Note: I don't have a plugin installed

Does anyone know how to disable this ?

Comment: If the source is available for the library code - IDE will navigate to the source automatically. Please add more details on what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This one is prepackaged, so it would be present even if you did not explicitly install it.

You can disable the "Java Bytecode Decompiler" Plugin. You can find it at Intellij Preferences -> Plugins -> Installed Tab. [image: Plugins]

Comment: Congratulations with 10K! I couldn't stay aside watching your 9995

Comment: But seriously, I think your answer is good

Comment: So, as I commented, I'm not using plugin. This plugin is disabled here for me!
But I managed to solve it in another way, I simply re-indexed the projects. Strange huh!